# Simple JQuery Menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I don't want to redesign the wheel and I'm not profficient in Javascript or JQuery, so if there's a script out there that will meet my needs, that's what I'm looking for.

I'm writing in C#/ASP.NET. I need a drop menu that works in the following way:

1. Can be configured w/out a Site map. Many of my actions are interactions within the same page, not navigations to a different page.  Actually, all of my actions are going to trigger postbacks to specific server side methods.
2. Drops down OnClick, not hover.  There are other hover actions in the vicinity of the menu and it gets annoying to have the menu dropping down if you accidently get too close.
3. Has keyboard shortcut functionality.

Should I write my own or is there a reputable script that you would recommend?

Comment: There are a gazillion and one jQuery menu plugins out there. Try Googling, and pick one, any one.

Comment: NP.  Just so you know, I did look at several but they were all "hover" menus.  I was having trouble finding one that was solid and configurable to click events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should inplement your menu in the form of a list placed beneath the main menu which you can show on click of your main menu heading by using simple jquery show hide.

For the shortcut implementation, this link might be helpful.

http://craig.is/killing/mice

Comment: Thanks. That shortcuts were the main reason I was avoiding my own, but that link looks pretty good.